# ContentObserver is not calling

Tags: android, android-service, contentobserver

OnChange method of ContactObserver is not calling unless i run application second time. The first run of which makes installation seems does not make register observer even onCreate is called from Service.

On the second run, it works flawless. You can see the code below.

```
public final class ContactSync extends Service {

private ContactObserver mObserver;

public ContactSync() {
    mObserver = new ContactObserver();
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.ProfileSyncState.CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);

    Logger.i("Sync service is ready");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

private void lookup() {
    RealmResults<Contact> all = Realm
            .getDefaultInstance()
            .where(Contact.class)
            .findAll();

    for (Contact proxy : all) {
        Contact concrete = Realm
                .getDefaultInstance()
                .copyFromRealm(proxy);

        Contact raw = ContactResolver
                .from(getApplicationContext())
                .setUri(concrete.data())
                .setPosition(concrete.mPosition)
                .query();

        if (raw == null) {
            delete(proxy);
        } else {
            update(raw);
        }
    }

    publish();
}

private void publish() {
    LocalBroadcastManager
            .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .sendBroadcastSync(new Intent(ContactEdge.PublishEvent.EVENT_PUBLISH));

    Logger.i("Published contacts");
}

private void update(@NonNull final Contact contact) {
    Realm
            .getDefaultInstance()
            .executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(contact);

                    Logger.json(contact);
                }
            });

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(
                getApplicationContext(), contact.getId())
                .setShortLabel(contact.getShortLabel())
                .setLongLabel(contact.getLongLabel())
                .setIcon(contact.getIcon(getApplicationContext()))
                .setIntent(contact.getIntent())
                .build();

        ShortcutManager manager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
        manager.addDynamicShortcuts(Collections.singletonList(shortcut));
    }

    Logger.i("Updated contact");
}

private void delete(@NonNull final Contact contact) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        ShortcutManager manager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
        manager.removeDynamicShortcuts(Collections.singletonList(contact.getId()));
    }

    Realm
            .getDefaultInstance()
            .executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    contact.deleteFromRealm();
                }
            });

    Logger.i("Deleted contact");
}

final class ContactObserver extends ContentObserver {

    ContactObserver() {
        super(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);

        lookup();
    }
}
```

My Application class :

```
public final class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Fresco.initialize(this);
    Realm.init(this);

    startContactSync();
}

private void startContactSync() {
    Intent service = new Intent(this, ContactSync.class);
    startService(service);
}
```

And xml element in application element of Manifest file.

```
        <service
        android:name=".ui.edge.contact.ContactSync"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems well, probably you are missing permission ?

Comment: Thanks for point. Thats explains why it does not work first time. Because permission is not granted yet.